# quickest R implementation of within

Tags: r, optimization, operators

I use `"%within[]%" <- function(x,y){x>=y[1] & x<=y[2]}` (meaning `x` is in the compact set `y`) a lot in R code but I am pretty sure It is awfully slow. Do you have something quicker ? It needs to work for everything where `>` is defined.

EDIT: `x` could be a vector and `y` a 2 elments vector in ascending order...

EDIT2: It is strange that nobody (to my knowledge) wrote a package `rOperator` implementing quick `C` operators like `%w/i[]%, %w/i[[%, ...`

EDIT3: I realized that my question was too general as making assumption on `x,y` would modify any result, I think we should close it, thanks for your input.

Comment: Do you mean that `y` is always a two-elements vector, with `y[1]<y[2]` ?

Comment: `function(…){return(…)}` => `function(…) …`

Comment: You probably want `&` instead of `&&`.

Comment: Well `&&` seems a bit faster than `&`, and you don't seem to need vector operations here, unless x is a vector.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
"%within[]%" <- function(x,y){x>=y[1] & x<=y[2]}

x <- 1:10
y <- c(3,5)

x %within[]% y
"%within[]2%" <- function(x,y) findInterval(x,y,rightmost.closed=TRUE)==1
x %within[]2% y

library(microbenchmark)

microbenchmark(x %within[]% y,x %within[]2% y)

Unit: microseconds
             expr   min    lq median    uq    max
1  x %within[]% y 1.849 2.465 2.6185 2.773 11.395
2 x %within[]2% y 4.928 5.544 5.8520 6.160 37.265

x <- 1:1e6
microbenchmark(x %within[]% y,x %within[]2% y)

Unit: milliseconds
             expr      min       lq   median       uq      max
1  x %within[]% y 27.81535 29.60647 31.25193 56.68517 88.16961
2 x %within[]2% y 20.75496 23.07100 24.37369 43.15691 69.62122
```

This probably is a job for Rcpp.

Comment: +1 TIL how to use `microbenchmark` correctly.

Answer (score 3):

You can get a small performance improvement with a simple Rcpp implementation:

```
library(Rcpp)
library(microbenchmark)

withinR <- function(x,y) x >= y[1] & x <= y[2]
cppFunction("LogicalVector withinCpp(const NumericVector& x, const NumericVector& y) {
  double min = y[0], max = y[1];

  int n = x.size();
  LogicalVector out(n);

  for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    double val = x[i];
    if (NumericVector::is_na(val)) {
      out[i] = NA_LOGICAL;
    } else {
      out[i] = val >= min & val <= max;
    }

  }
  return out;
}")

x <- sample(100, 1e5, rep = T)

stopifnot(all.equal(withinR(x, c(25, 50)), withinCpp(x, c(25, 50))))

microbenchmark(
  withinR(x, c(25, 50)),
  withinCpp(x, c(25, 50))
)
```

The C++ version is about 4x faster on my computer. You could probably tweak it further still if you wanted to use more Rcpp tricks, but this seems pretty fast already. Even the R version would need to be called very frequently before it was likely to a bottleneck.

```
# Unit: microseconds
#                      expr  min   lq median   uq  max
# 1 withinCpp(x, c(25, 50))  635  659    678 1012 27385
# 2   withinR(x, c(25, 50)) 1969 2031   2573 2954 4082
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, I don't know if this could be considered slow or not, but here is a bit of benchmark :

```
R> within <- function(x,y){return(x>=y[1] & x<=y[2])}
R> microbenchmark(within(2,c(1,5)))
Unit: microseconds
               expr   min     lq median    uq    max neval
 within(2, c(1, 5)) 2.667 2.8305 2.9045 2.969 15.818   100

R> within2 <- function(x,y) x>=y[1] & x<=y[2]
R> microbenchmark(within2(2,c(1,5)))
Unit: microseconds
                expr   min     lq median    uq    max neval
 within2(2, c(1, 5)) 2.266 2.3205  2.398 2.483 12.472   100

R> microbenchmark(2>=1 & 2<=5)
Unit: nanoseconds
            expr min    lq median  uq  max neval
 2 >= 1 & 2 <= 5 781 821.5    850 911 5701   100
```

So it seems that omitting the `return`, as suggested by Konrad Rudolph, speeds up things a bit. But not writing a function is much faster.

Comment: My suggestion wasn’t actually so much about performance as about style (the `return` function call is simply redundant here). But yes, not surprised by these results.

Comment: && only compares the first elements of the vectors: 1:4 < 4 && 1:4 > 2 gives FALSE and not (FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE)

Comment: @JanvanderLaan Yes, I know, but if you don't want a vectorized operation, `&&` is a bit faster.

Comment: @juba: I edited for vectors as my use case is more likely vectorial.

Comment: @statquant Ok, updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Tree-based structures offer better performances if `x` contains many values. If you can limit your requirements to numerical values, there are 2 options

An implementation of interval trees for integers can be found in the Bioconductor package [IRanges](http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/2.11/bioc/html/IRanges.html).

By default RSQLite is compiling the embedded SQLite library with [rtrees](http://www.sqlite.org/rtree.html) enabled. This could be used with any numerical value.

Comment: I realized that this is more complex than I thought, ideally this should work with numeric (so everything like date,POSIXct...) but also character (with lexicographic order).

Comment: Converting dates to integers (milliseconds since epoch) is trivial (your pseudonym suggests that you are not working with historical or pre-historical dates). Strings are little special and how to do it would require design decisions from you (prefix matching ? suffix matching ? strictly identical lengths ?)

Comment: Yep, not sure a conversion is even needed as POSIXct and Date are stored as double (strangely for Date) internally. Understood for strings...